# Excel Formula to convert string to array format

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I've a word test,i would like to convert it to "test"=>"test".

I've many words like this,i would like to convert it.

Which formula does this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you explain us more what is the difference between the input and the output?

Comment: @JMax:Input is test and output is "test"=>"test".

Comment: @JMax:This is what i tried ="test",i first thought of moving step by step.My initial step was to convert test into "test" so wrote a formula like this ="test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let assume you have in cell `A1` the value: `test`

You can put in cell `A2` this formula:

```
=""""&A1&""">="""&A1&""""
```

This will give:

```
"test"=>"test"
```